# Can I Avoid Passing Default Value of Optional Parameters?

Tags: c#

**Background:**

This method accepts 3 optional parameters (with default values)

```
public void Test(string Name, int p1 = 1, int p2 = 2, int p3 = 3)
{
   // do something
}
```

Can be called by:

```
Test("Something");
```

If I need to override `p1`:

```
Test("Something", 5);
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to override `p3` without passing values to `p1` and `p2`? so I can use default values of `p1` and `p2` without passing them.

I need something like:

```
Test("Something", default, default, 50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by specify the param name

```
Test("Something", p3:50)
```